# How to show pop up notification on reminder app?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on an reminder type java application using javafx which will remind me about tasks showing pop up on desktop about the task.But i don't know how to do it.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, consider showing others _what you have tried_ or the _research you have done_ and _why it hasn't worked_. For more information on how to ask a good question, see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: What version of Java/JavaFX are you using?

Comment: Look into [`ControlsFX`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) [`Notifications`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html).

Answer (score 0):

**The Reminder Notification Mechanism**

This assumes using *JavaFX 8*. The reminder has date and time fields. The app displays an alert dialog (`javafx.scene.control.Alert` control) whenever a reminder is due.

The notification mechanism is implemented using the `Timer` and `TimerTask` API of `java.util` package. Timer is a facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals. The task is defined by extending a `TimerTask`. This is an abstract class which implements `Runnable`; the `run()` method has code for the action of this task.

There are two tasks defined for reminder notification. The first one is run once at the start of the app; this checks for all the overdue reminders and shows them in reminder alerts. The next task is scheduled to run at a regular interval, every minute (or whatever is the desired time interval) for the duration of the app.

The following code snippet shows the initialization of the timer and timer's task at the start of the app:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
RemindersTask tasks = new RemindersTask();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasks, zeroDelay, periodOneMinute);
```

**The Reminders Task**

The class `RemindersTask.java` extends the `TimerTask` and overrides the `run()` abstract method. The `run` method has code to check for due or overdue reminders and display the reminder alert.

In the following code snippet the `getDueRems()` method retrieves all the due reminders based on the supplied predicate (of type `java.util.function.Predicate`). Initially, the predicate value is set as: `Predicate<Reminder> predicate = ReminderPredicates.OVER_DUE;` - this notifies all the due reminders until the start of the app - all overdue reminders. After the first run of the task, the predicate is reset to `ReminderPredicates.DUE_NOW` and is run at a regular interval set at the start of the scheduling the timer.

The following code snippet shows the run method for the timer task:

```
public void run() {
    List<Reminder> dueRems = getDueRems();
    showNotifications(dueRems); // shows the multiple notifications in an alert dialog
    predicate = ReminderPredicates.DUE_NOW;
}

private List<Reminder> getDueRems() {
    ObservableList<Reminder> rems = dataClass.getAllReminders();
    return rems.stream()
        .filter(predicate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**The Reminder Predicates**

A `java.util.function.Predicate<T>` is a functional interface and represents a predicate (a boolean-valued function) of one argument (`T` is the input type).

Here are some example predicate definitions (defined in `ReminderPredicates` class as constants), and others may be defined based on the requirements:

```
Predicate<Reminder> TODAYS = r -> r.getDate().isEqual(LocalDate.now());
Predicate<Reminder> COMPLETED = r -> (r.getCompleted() == true);
Predicate<Reminder> DUE_NOW = TODAYS.and(COMPLETED.negate());
```